# What is the bird that are on house and make sound during part of the night?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

For a few weeks, my neighbour is disturbed by a sound that seems to comes from me. It's mostly heard at the end of a day, but he said the sound stops in the night.

After checking, yes, it seems to be in multiple houses, but comes from the top of house. The sound stops when we are very near it (like 3-5 meters).

I tried to show them, like check if I can see some part of bird, but nothing.

I made few recordings. **WARNING**: all record are very low in sound, can't do better yet. Sorry for the noise. They are all hosted by discord.

Latest sound that seems not so bad: [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/991450082228584678/991472415764922478/Enregistrement_1.wav) (doesn't require download)

Record that require download:

- [First sound](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/991450082228584678/991451769248952461/Strange_sound_2.aac)
- [Second sound](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/991450082228584678/991451769446080543/Strange_sound_1.aac)

Doesn't require download:

- [Third sound](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/991450082228584678/991453958914715799/28_juin_a_23.22.wav)
- [Third sound but with noise removed](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/991450082228584678/991458674587484180/ab46966e393cc6a7e793c872410c9bc1.wav)

Do you know what are those things and how to prevent them? Do you need more things to identify them?

External information:

- I'm in the middle of France.
- All sounds have been recorded today.

Comment: Much better, I'll leave it to the experts who can tell and delete my old comments now.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.chant-oiseaux.fr/ by chance? There are a lot of bird sounds there, and you may be able to find it.

Comment: I'd start with common baby birds - Common Starling (*Sturnus vulgaris*) is a likely target as is black bird (*Turdus merula*).